# Join two or more queries in mongo db node.js and get result as a single object using aggregate query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections as follows:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  title: String,
  details: String,
  location: String,
  rate: String,

  status: {
    type: String,
    default: "active",
  },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
  },
});

const Project = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);

export default Project;
```

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const proposalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Project" },
  rate: String,
  message: String,

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
  },
});

const Proposal = mongoose.model("Proposal", proposalSchema);

export default Proposal;
```

And in response to a GET request, I want to get all the projects which are active and user has not sent the proposal to them, GET request will have the id of user.

(Proposal: When a user sends a proposal, a proposal object is created in proposals collections which has userId and ProjectId)

I have make it work using the below queries but it doesn't looks efficient and good. Is there a way I can get this result using aggregate query or any better way from this?

And also how I can efficiently can convert objectId to string Id here.

```
export const getProjects = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const activeProjects = await Project.find({ status: "active" }, { _id: 1 });

    const projectsWithProposals = await Proposal.find(
      {
        $and: [
          { userId: req.query.id },
          { projectId: { $in: activeProjects } },
        ],
      },
      { _id: 0, projectId: 1 }
    );

    const stringsIds = projectsWithProposals.map((id) =>
      id.projectId.toString()
    );

    const projects = await Project.find({
      $and: [{ status: "active" }, { _id: { $nin: stringsIds } }],
    });
    res.status(200).json(projects);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a aggregation function which delivers all Projects which have no proposal from a given user:

```
function getQ (userId) {
   return [
      {
         "$match": {
            "$expr": {
               "$eq": [
                  "$status",
                  "active"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$lookup": {
            "from": "proposals",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "projectId",
            "as": "proposals"
         }
      },
      {
         "$set": {
            "uids": "$proposals.userId"
         }
      },
      {
         "$unset": "proposals"
      },
      {
         "$match": {
            "$expr": {
               "$not": [
                  {
                     "$in": [
                        mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
                        "$uids"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$unset": "uids"
      },
      {
         "$limit": 10
      }
   ]
}

db.Project.aggregate(getQ("62a61df204f2ce244ce0ffcc")) // input is user._id
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

I have used the standard mongoose _ids so you might have to adapt the code if required.

The query does only output the `Project` collection data, although it would be easy to include other data as well.

Beware that `limit` is constant here. You could also convert `skip` and `limit` to function paramters which would make the function much more flexible if you are working with huge amounts of results.